# How do you access a file selected through a form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Ruby code which sets up a form to select a file:

```
    <%= form_for :import, :url=>{:controller=>"products", :action=>"import"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <div class= "field">
            <%= f.file_field :import %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Import' %>
        </div>
```

In the controller, I am trying to call the file that was selected from the local drive. This line works for a specific file:

```
    book = Spreadsheet.open 'c:/source.xls'
```

But I don't know how to call up in a controller the file that was selected from the form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The file data will be in the `params[:import][:import]`, not in an actual file. Once the file is uploaded, there is nothing like "c:/...".

If needed, open a new file, and write that data in it.

Or use something like carrierwave to do it for you, and get the actual path of the file once saved.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check out carrierwave.

Comment: Thanks @saverio. I was able to apply carrierwave and it works fine now.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer and cast an upvote. It's the usual thing people do here when someone solves their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that now works:

def import

```
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
import_file = params[ :import ][ :import ]
file = FileUploader.new
file.store!(import_file)
book = Spreadsheet.open "#{file.store_path}"
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
sheet1.each 1 do |row|
@product = Product.new(:code => row[0], :name => row[1], :status => row[2], :account => current_user.account).save
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following plugins to handle file uploading.

`attachement_fu` and `paperclip`.

Here is a tutorial on railscast for paperclip http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip and here is an attachement fu tutorial http://clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/2007/02/24#FileUploadFu